# Facebook Stream Publish while offline

Tags: facebook

If I have the publish_stream extended permission for a Facebook app, does that allow my app to write on my feed while I'm offline?

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publishing To User's Wall Without Being Online/Logged-in - Facebook Sharing Using Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/publishing-to-users-wall-without-being-online-logged-in-facebook-sharing-using)

Answer (score 8):

You don't need the offline_access permission to post to a user's feed, so long as you have the publish_stream permission.  Here's an excerpt from the "publish_stream" section of [Facebook's Doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) :

**publish_stream**
With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_access.

To do this, you need to first retrieve your app's access token by calling this API:

**GET URL** `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials`

Once you have the app access_token, you can post to the user's feed:

**POST URL** `https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/feed`

**POST BODY** `access_token={app_access_token}&message=Hello`

Comment: I can verify it works, more info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Phillip, there are 2 steps. Which one didn't work for you and what error message are you getting from Facebook?  I just did it using Fiddler and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone stumbles on this looking for a solution using PHP.  Using the [PHP API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/), I ended up with this working for me, with help from the FB docs here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Note that $users_facebook_id is the Facebook ID of a user who has granted your app permissions with the "publish_stream" permission.

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/'.$users_facebook_id.'/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                   'link' => 'http://www.website.com',
                                   'message' => 'Testing'
                                  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

yes facebook allow you to publish offline just take the offline_access permission from the user and when he/she is going to use you application , then user need not to be login on facebook to publish .
please refer this :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: About publish_stream permission: ...With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_acces... so apparently no offline_access permission is needed.Only doesn't say how.

Answer (score 0):

offline_access is no longer used in facebook, the new way is the Expiration Time of the TOKEN through New Endpoint 
read more at https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/